# How to merge String?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It is possible to merge two String  with Angularjs function ?:

```
"123456"
"ABC"
```

to :

```
"ABC456"
```

Thankx

Comment: Don't fall into the trap of thinking that because you're using Angular, _every_ part of your application has to be specifically 'Angular code'. String manipulation/concatenation is easy in JavaScript, so save yourself the headache and do it in plain JavaScript!

Comment: string can be concatenated by `+` sign

Comment: He is not asking for concatenation

Comment: You're right @JoeClay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
var str1  = "123456";
var str2  = "ABC";
console.log(str2 + str1.substring(str2.length));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`String.prototype.substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) function:

```js
var a = "123456";
var b = "ABC";

var res = b + a.substr(b.length);

document.write(res);
```